# USB 2 connection to USB 3

Tags: usb-hub

I want to design a chip level circuit to connect USB 3 port to several USB 2 devices. I think the best way is using a Hub like TUSB8041, TI 4 port hub USB 3. As far as I know, the USB 2 and 3 are compatible, then it seems that simply I can connect four USB2 to the USB 3 hub connections, then I have 4xUSB2 is connected to one USB3. 
But the problem is that in USB2 Devices we have D+ and D- for data and in the USB3  we have SSRX- SSRX+ SSTX- and SSTX+.
in summary, 
1) is it correct to connect 4xUSB2 to one USB3 in a USB3 Hub?
2) how can I connect a 4-pin USB2 device to a 5-pin USB 3?

Answer (score 1):

You simply only connect the D-, D+, and GND lines, and leave the SS lines open (I literally did this quite recently, using the exact same HUB IC from TI). See below comparing the two:

[image]

Hope this helps. Also, you'll find that USB 3.0/3.1 is 9 pins, not 5 as you said (VBUS, D-, D+, SSTX-, SSTX+, GND, SSRX-, SSRX+, and GND).

Comment: would you please make me sure that by connecting USB2 to the USB3 hub, is it like that the full bandwidth of USB3 spreades to 10xUSB2?  and it works like this? if so, do you know how I can cascade the hube? is it possible to connect 2 hubs to another to make 8 to one hub out of 2x4 port hub?

Comment: @BOB, no, the USB8041 is not able to aggregate USB2 traffic from its downstream ports into USB3 on its upstream port. AFAIK, the USB standard does not even allow for such a thing.

Comment: Thank you, but it is a little frustrating for me, so there is no way to aggregate USB2 traffic to USB3 upstream. Then, what is the benefit of connecting USB2 in the above figure to USB3 hub while there is the specific pathway for USB2 in the hub?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I connect a 4-pin USB2 device to a 5-pin USB 3?

You can simply not connect the Superspeed transmit and receive pins.

> is it correct to connect 4xUSB2 to one USB3 in a USB3 Hub?

You can do that, but you will just be using the USB3 hub as a USB2 hub.

The USB3 hub chip essentially has two circuits inside: A USB2 hub and a USB3 hub. These circuits don't have any way to move data between them. You would only be using the USB2 hub part of the chip, and it will not use the bandwidth of the USB3 upstream connection to carry the data from the USB 2 devices connected on the downstream ports.

It would probably be at least slightly cheaper to just buy a USB2 hub.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that such a bandwidth sharing needs specific design.